# Highcharts printing complete chart while zoomed in

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using highcharts library for a project using an Angular 8 front-end and DRF(Django Rest Framework) as backend. I'd like to be able to print the complete chart while zoomed in. By default when I zoom in using the navigator (located at the bottom) and I try and print the chart I can only print whatever part of the chart that is displayed on the screen. I would like to able to print the rest of the chart as well.

I'm looking at a solution, a gist of which is below:

1. Check if the chart is zoomed-in if it is zoomed-in I get the x-axis extremes (min date, max date), and calculate the time interval.
2. I set up my own export server using [highcharts-export-server](https://www.highcharts.com/blog/news/256-introducing-the-highcharts-node-js-export-server/) and using the time interval calculated in the first step, I create multiple PNGs/JPEGs of the complete chart. I then place them in a pdf and return that pdf in response. I won't be exactly printing out the chart but it would provide the user with the ability to print the pdf.

Below is the fiddle of the kind of chart I'm working on:
https://jsfiddle.net/x7qz6k12/

```
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.highcharts.com/css/annotations/popup.css">
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/drag-panes.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/indicators.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/bollinger-bands.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/indicators/ema.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/annotations-advanced.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/full-screen.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/price-indicator.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/stock-tools.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

    <style>
            /* FULL SCREEN */
        
       
            /* Responsive design */
        
            @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
                .highcharts-stocktools-toolbar li>.highcharts-menu-item-title {
                    display: none;
                }
                .highcharts-stocktools-toolbar li ul li {
                    width: auto;
                }
            }
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="chart-wrapper">
        <div class="highcharts-popup highcharts-popup-annotations">
            <span class="highcharts-close-popup">&times;</span>
            <div class="highcharts-popup-wrapper">
                <label for="stroke">Color</label>
                <input type="text" name="stroke" />
                <label for="stroke-width">Width</label>
                <input type="text" name="stroke-width" />
            </div>
            <button>Save</button>
        </div>

        <div id="container" class="chart"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>

    function addPopupEvents(chart) {
        var closePopupButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('highcharts-close-popup');
        // Close popup button:
        Highcharts.addEvent(
            closePopupButtons[0],
            'click',
            function () {
                this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            }
        );

        Highcharts.addEvent(
            closePopupButtons[1],
            'click',
            function () {
                this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
            }
        );

        // Update an annotaiton from popup
        Highcharts.addEvent(
            document.querySelectorAll('.highcharts-popup-annotations button')[0],
            'click',
            function () {
                var strokeWidth = parseInt(
                        document.querySelectorAll(
                            '.highcharts-popup-annotations input[name="stroke-width"]'
                        )[0].value,
                        10
                    ),
                    strokeColor = document.querySelectorAll(
                        '.highcharts-popup-annotations input[name="stroke"]'
                    )[0].value;

                // Stock/advanced annotations have common options under typeOptions
                if (chart.currentAnnotation.options.typeOptions) {
                    chart.currentAnnotation.update({
                        typeOptions: {
                            lineColor: strokeColor,
                            lineWidth: strokeWidth,
                            line: {
                                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                                stroke: strokeColor
                            },
                            background: {
                                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                                stroke: strokeColor
                            },
                            innerBackground: {
                                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                                stroke: strokeColor
                            },
                            outerBackground: {
                                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                                stroke: strokeColor
                            },
                            connector: {
                                strokeWidth: strokeWidth,
                                stroke: strokeColor
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Basic annotations:
                    chart.currentAnnotation.update({
                        shapes: [{
                            'stroke-width': strokeWidth,
                            stroke: strokeColor
                        }],
                        labels: [{
                            borderWidth: strokeWidth,
                            borderColor: strokeColor
                        }]
                    });
                }
                chart.stockToolbar.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
            }
        );
    }



    chartdata = []

    for ( var i = 0; i < 22; i++ ) {
        chartdata.push(0);
        chartdata.push(0);
        chartdata.push(0);
        chartdata.push(0);
        chartdata.push(0);
        chartdata.push(-0.25);
        chartdata.push(0.5);
        chartdata.push(-0.25)
    }

    Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
        chart: {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    addPopupEvents(this);
                }
            },
            borderWidth:0.5,
            borderColor:'#000000',
            backgroundColor:'#fff'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 2,
                states: {
                    inactive: {
                        opacity: 1,

                    },
                    hover: {
                        //color: "red",
                        opacity: 1,
                        lineWidth: 1,
                    },
                },
            },
        },
        
        tooltip: {
            //shared: true,
            crosshairs: true,
            shape: 'square',
            headerShape: 'callout',
            borderWidth: 0,
            shadow: false,
            positioner: function (width, height, point) {
                var chart = this.chart,
                    position;

                if (point.isHeader) {
                    position = {
                        x: Math.max(
                            // Left side limit
                            chart.plotLeft,
                            Math.min(
                                point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - width / 2,
                                // Right side limit
                                chart.chartWidth - width - chart.marginRight
                            )
                        ),
                        y: point.plotY
                    };
                } else {
                    position = {
                        x: point.series.chart.plotLeft,
                        y: point.series.yAxis.top - chart.plotTop
                    };
                }

                return position;
            }
        },
        
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
        
        rangeSelector: {
            inputEnabled:true,
            buttonPosition: {
            },
            buttons: [{
                type: 'minute',
                count: 1,
                text: '1m'
                }, {
                type: 'minute',
                count: 3,
                text: '3m'
                }, {
                type: 'minute',
                count: 6,
                text: '6m'
                }, {
                type: 'minute',
                text: '10m'
                },{
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
        },
        
        navigation: {
            bindings: {
                thresholds: {
                    className: 'highcharts-threshold-annotation',
                    start: function (event) {
                        var chart = this.chart,
                            x = chart.xAxis[0].toValue(event.chartX),
                            y = chart.yAxis[1].toValue(event.chartY);

                        chart.addAnnotation({
                            labels: [{
                                point: {
                                x: x,
                                y: y,
                                yAxis: 1,
                                xAxis: 0
                                },
                                text: 'This is my note',
                            }]
                        });
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        xAxis:{
            gridLineWidth:1,
            labels:{
                enabled:false
            },
            gridLineDashStyle: 'longdashdot',
        },
        
        yAxis: [{
                height: '25%',
                resize: {
                    enabled: true,
                },
                labels: {
                    x:0,
                    enabled: true,
                },
                gridLineWidth: 2,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite:false,
                offset: 0,
                showEmpty: false
                
            },{
                showEmpty: false,
                top: '25%',
                height: '25%',
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                labels: {
                    enabled: false,
                    align:'left',
                    x:5,
                    y:-3.2,
                    color:'#000000'
                },
                showFirstLabel:true,
                showLastLabel:true,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions:[0,300],
                min: 0,
                max: 300*1.15,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite:false,
                plotLines: [{
                    color: 'red', // Color value
                    dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                    value: 100, // Value of where the line will appear
                    width: 1 // Width of the line    
                },
                {
                    color: 'red', // Color value
                    dashStyle: 'longdashdot', // Style of the plot line. Default to solid
                    value: 250, // Value of where the line will appear
                    width: 1 // Width of the line    
                }],
            },{
                top: '50%',
                height: '25%',
                resize: {
                    enabled: true
                },
                labels: { 
                    enabled: true,
                    align:'left',
                    x:5,
                    y:-3.2,
                    color:'#000000'
                },
                offset: 0,
                startOnTick: true,
                endOnTick: false,
                tickPositions:[0,0.5],
                min: 0,
                max: 0.5*1.15,
                showFirstLabel:true,
                showLastLabel:true,
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite:false
            },{
                top: '75%',
                height: '25%',
                offset: 0,
                labels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                gridLineWidth: 0,
                minorGridLineWidth: 0,
                opposite:false,
            }],

        navigationBindings: {
            events: {
                selectButton: function (event) {
                    var newClassName = event.button.className + ' highcharts-active',
                        topButton = event.button.parentNode.parentNode;

                    if (topButton.classList.contains('right')) {
                        newClassName += ' right';
                    }

                    // If this is a button with sub buttons,
                    // change main icon to the current one:
                    if (!topButton.classList.contains('highcharts-menu-wrapper')) {
                        topButton.className = newClassName;
                    }

                    // Store info about active button:
                    this.chart.activeButton = event.button;
                },
                deselectButton: function (event) {
                    event.button.parentNode.parentNode.classList.remove('highcharts-active');

                    // Remove info about active button:
                    this.chart.activeButton = null;
                },
                showPopup: function (event) {

                    if (!this.indicatorsPopupContainer) {
                        this.indicatorsPopupContainer = document
                            .getElementsByClassName('highcharts-popup-indicators')[0];
                    }

                    if (!this.annotationsPopupContainer) {
                        this.annotationsPopupContainer = document
                            .getElementsByClassName('highcharts-popup-annotations')[0];
                    }

                    if (event.formType === 'indicators') {
                        this.indicatorsPopupContainer.style.display = 'block';
                    } else if (event.formType === 'annotation-toolbar') {
                        // If user is still adding an annotation, don't show popup:
                        if (!this.chart.activeButton) {
                            this.chart.currentAnnotation = event.annotation;
                            this.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'block';
                        }
                    }

                },
                closePopup: function () {
                    this.indicatorsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
                    this.annotationsPopupContainer.style.display = 'none';
                }
            }
        },
        
        stockTools: {
            gui: {
                enabled: false
            },
            definitions: {
                thresholds: {
                    className: 'highcharts-threshold-annotation',
                    symbol: 'horizontal-line.svg'
                }
            }
        },

        series: [
            {
                type: "line",
                data: chartdata,
                marker: {
                    enabled:false
                },
                yAxis: 0,
                name: 'QRS',
                color: '#ff002f'
                
            },{
                type: "line",
                data: data = [
                    300,300,300,290,280,270,260,250,240,230,220,218,216,214,212,210,208,206,204,202,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,200,
                    200,200
                ],
                marker: {
                    enabled:false
                },
                yAxis: 1,
                name: 'HR',
                color:'#034d00'
                
            },{
                type: "spline",
                data: [
                    0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2, 
                    0.3,0.3,0.3,0.29,0.28,0.27,0.26,0.25,0.24,0.23,0.22,0.218,0.216,0.214,0.212,0.21,0.208,0.206,0.204,0.202,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3,0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,
                    0.3,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2,
                    0.3,0.3, 0.3, 0.2, 0.3,0.1, 0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2, 0.3,0.2,0.2,0.4, 0.0,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,
                    0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,
                    0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,
                    0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3, 0.2,0.3,0.3,0.2
                ],
                marker: {
                    enabled:false
                },
                yAxis: 2,
                name: 'Impedence',
                color: '#001aff'
            },{
                type: "spline",
                data: data = [
                    0.3,0.3,0.3,0.29,0.28,0.27,0.26,0.25,0.24,0.23,0.22,0.218,0.216,0.214,0.212,0.21,0.208,0.206,0.204,0.202,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2,
                    0.2,0.2
                ],
                marker: {
                    enabled:false
                },
                yAxis: 3,
                name: 'Resp. Rate',
                color:'#ff002f'
            },
            // {
            // type:'area',
            // name:'band',
            // marker:{enabled:false},
            // lineWidth:0,
            // color:'rgba(156,156,156,.5)',
            // data:[[1.5,0],[1.5,80],[2.25,80],[2.25,0]]
                
            // }
        ],

        responsive: {
                rules: [{
                    condition: {
                        maxWidth: 800
                    },
                    chartOptions: {
                        rangeSelector: {
                            inputEnabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe using the `render` callback with the flag `chart.renderer.forExport` to check if the chart is rendered for exporting will be a good solution? Inside this `if` condition you should be able to set wanted extremes. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/a7jn4q2u/

Comment: Alright, going to try this.